# c# Winforms share resources between projects

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution that contains 2 winforms app and a classlibrary referenced by the 2 apps... I added some images in resource

[image: resources from class library]

but when I go on the winform app and try to add the image into a button appears this:

[image: load resource]

Is there a way to do this?

thanks

Comment: would [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24151524/how-can-i-share-resources-across-multiple-projects-within-a-c-sharp-solution) help? or may be [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100455/issue-with-shared-winforms-resources-across-projects-in-visual-studio)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make resource items public instead internal.

To do this, in .resx file in solution explorer select Property Window (Alt+Enter) and in **File Properties -> Custom Tool** should be **ResXFileCodeGenerator**

Change this option to **PublicResXFileCodeGenerator** (if option don't show in dropdown field, don't worry aboit it, write/type **PublicResXFileCodeGenerator** in field)

After that  resources member class will be generated with public modifier and you can access to it from any project that reference assembly.

I hope it can help you!